# How to connect in parallel virtual machines in order to exploit all available resources?

Tags: parallel-processing, mpi, chemistry

I want to connect in parallel 40 virtual machines in order to run a quantum chemistry program in parallel. Each one of the virtual machines has a different inet6 address and all of them are connected to the internet. The reason that I need to combine the virtual machines is because the administrators limit down to 8gb ram and 60gb hard drive per virtual machine.

My question is how is it possible to connect them in parallel so that all available resources will be used?

Comment: Is it an MPI-based program?

Comment: Thank you for the response. Some modules of the program ORCA are MPI based. In the manual it is stated that Parallel ORCA can be used with OpenMPI only.